# PHP PDO statement with Sum and other column fails

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to run an SQL query with PDO

This works

```
$result = $dbo->query("SELECT sum(c) as scfus 
    FROM tbl 
    WHERE 
        YEAR(ondate)=YEAR('".$_POST['startdate']."') 
        AND MONTH(ondate)=MONTH('".$_POST['startdate']."') 
        AND DAY(ondate)=$i");
```

but this does not

```
$result = $dbo->query("SELECT a,b,sum(c) as scfus 
    FROM tbl 
    WHERE 
        YEAR(ondate)=YEAR('".$_POST['startdate']."')
        AND MONTH(ondate)=MONTH('".$_POST['startdate']."') 
        AND DAY(ondate)=$i");
```

The only difference is the addition of the a,b column names to the query.

I can run this query (both of them) directly into mysql and get a single record back, as expected, but PDO does not seem to like column names AND sum in the same query?

I can't see a reason, or solution. New to PDO, so was never an issue for me before.

Thanks.

UPDATE - OK, I still think this should work fine, but as a workaround, I've run 2 sql statements, almost exactly the same. One with SELECT SUM(x), one with SELECT a,b, but without the sum. Works fine, but I really should be able to do it in one statement, unless I'm into some PDO limitation I'm not aware of yet.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: `SUM()` is an aggregate function. If you want to use it and fetch other columns as well, you need `GROUP BY`. Here's the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment re sql injections. I'm aware, but still very much unpublished code in test phase. I'll fix it up, if I can get it working.

Comment: This all depends on `a` and `b` are, if they're unique within the result set you can `GROUP BY a,b` so MySQL would not complain about non-aggregated columns in the result set. If they are not unique then it doesn't actually make sense to select them

Answer (score 0):

you might need to `GROUP BY c` (or whatever column you may want to group domain aggregate function `SUM()` by) in order to obtain the desired result-set... and maybe take the suggestion above into account.

Comment: Thanks for responses. SQL is correct and works as expected on the mysql console. GROUP BY is not needed.  I want a SUM of the column for ALL the records returned . The query works directly to mysql and via the old mysql_query() type.  I tried adding group by ID (there is a criteria in the statement that says where id=x), but it makes no difference. I don't understand why the query works in the mysql console, but not as a query via PDO. I would also add, the basic pdo code must be correct as if I just comment out the a,b, part, so it's just SUM() etc, it works, but I need those field names too.

Comment: I think I git your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way for your query, worked for me for what you want to achieve :

> $result = $dbo->query("SELECT a,b,(SELECT sum(c) as whateverFROM tbl),
>   as scfus 
>       FROM tbl 
>       WHERE 
>           YEAR(ondate)=YEAR('".$_POST['startdate']."')
>           AND MONTH(ondate)=MONTH('".$_POST['startdate']."') 
>           AND DAY(ondate)=$i");

SUM returns only one line so you'll never get all your results and only the ones of the first matching WHERE criterias (it registers first record found, then only count what it needs).

It will work

Oh, btw, make a timestamp of the date, make a string of the date post in the date sql format and check

```
WHERE date = $_POST['date']
```

Answer (score 0):

will work
SELECT a, b , (SELECT SUM(ID)*30 FROM table) FROM table WHERE ID = SOME(SELECT ID FROM tables WHERE users_ID = idYouWant);